# Fixing glRasterPos() position?

Tags: c, opengl

I am working on a OPENGL with C project. In this project, a ball will be there and it will have random motion, colliding with the walls of window and moving in a random direction. the player needs to click on the ball and the score which is displayed on top left corner will be incremented by 1 and the speed of the ball will increase by 1. We also have timer displayed on top right of 1 min. After 1 min the game will be over and the final score will be displayed to the player.

So far I have done the random motion of the ball. Score text displayed. The problem is that score is moving with the ball, it is not static on the top left corner. So how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define PI 3.14159265f

//Variable defined outside globally 

GLfloat ballRadius = 0.2;   //Radius of the bouncing ball
GLfloat ballX = 0.0f;   //Ball's center(x,y) position
GLfloat ballY = 0.0f;
GLfloat ballXMax,ballXMin,ballYMax,ballYMin;    //Ball's center (x,y) bounds
GLfloat xSpeed = 0.02f;  //Ball's speed in x and y direction
GLfloat ySpeed = 0.007f;
int refreshMills = 30;  
int x1,xa,ya; //refresh period in milliseconds
int score=0;
int last_mx = 0, last_my = 0, cur_mx = 0, cur_my = 0;
int arcball_on = false;
//Projection clipping area
GLdouble clipAreaXLeft,clipAreaXRight,clipAreaYBottom,clipAreaYTop;


// Initialize OpenGL Graphics

void initGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);                //Set background(clear) color to green


}


// Callback handler for window re-paint event

void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  //Clear the color buffer

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);        //To operate on the model-view matrix

    glLoadIdentity();    //Reset model-view matrix
    glTranslatef(ballX,ballY,0.0f);  //Translate to (xPos,yPos)

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);    //Use triangular segments to form a circle
    glColor3ub( rand()%1000, rand()%1000, rand()%1000 );     //Red
    glVertex2f(0.0f,0.0f);      //Center of circle
    int numSegments = 100;      //ball shape temp...

    GLfloat angle;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=numSegments;i++)   //Last vertex same as first vertex
    {
        angle = i*2.0f*PI/numSegments;   //360 degree for all segments
        glVertex2f(cos(angle)*ballRadius,sin(angle)*ballRadius);


    }
    glEnd();    
    glFlush();  //Swap front and back buffers

    //Animation Control - compute the location for next refresh
    ballX += xSpeed;
    ballY += ySpeed;

    //Check if the ball exceeds the edges
    if(ballX > ballXMax)
    {   xa=ballX;
        ballX = ballXMax;
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;

    }
    else if(ballX < ballXMin)
    {   xa=ballX;
        ballX = ballXMin;
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;

    }
    if(ballY > ballYMax)
    {   ya=ballY;
        ballY = ballYMax;
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;

    }
    else if(ballY < ballYMin)
    {   ya=ballY;
        ballY = ballYMin;
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;

    }

     glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    glRasterPos2f(-1.0,0.0);
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'S');
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'C');
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'O');
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'R');
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'E');
    glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,':');
    glFlush();
}

void onMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
  if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
    arcball_on = true;
    last_mx = cur_mx = x;
    last_my = cur_my = y;
  } else {
    arcball_on = false;

    if(cur_mx==x && cur_my==y)
    {
        score=score+1;
    }
    printf("%d",score);
  }
}

void onMotion(int x, int y) {
  if (arcball_on) {  // if left button is pressed
    cur_mx = x;
    cur_my = y;
  }
}

/*void mouseClicks(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
   utton == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
}
*/

//Call back when the windows is re-sized

void reshape(GLsizei width,GLsizei height)
{

    //Compute aspect ratio of the new window
    if(height ==0) height = 1;                                 //To prevent divide by 0                         
    GLfloat aspect = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;

    //Set the viewport to cover the new window
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    //Set the aspect ratio of the clipping area to match the viewport
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    //To operate on the Projection matrix
    glLoadIdentity();               //Reset the Projection Matrix
    if(width >=height)
    {
        clipAreaXLeft = -1.0 * aspect;
        clipAreaXRight = 1.0 * aspect;
        clipAreaYBottom = -1.0;
        clipAreaYTop = 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        clipAreaXLeft = -1.0;
        clipAreaXRight = 1.0 ;
        clipAreaYBottom = -1.0 / aspect;
        clipAreaYTop = 1.0 / aspect;
    }
    gluOrtho2D(clipAreaXLeft,clipAreaXRight,clipAreaYBottom,clipAreaYTop+0.25);
    ballXMin = clipAreaXLeft + ballRadius;
    ballXMax =  clipAreaXRight - ballRadius;
    ballYMin =  clipAreaYBottom + ballRadius;
    ballYMax =  clipAreaYTop - ballRadius;
}

//Call back when the timer expired

void Timer(int value)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();       //Post a paint request to activate display()
    glutTimerFunc(refreshMills,Timer,5);    //subsequent timer call at milliseconds

}

int windowWidth = 500;  //Window mode's width
int windowHeight = 500; //Window mode's height
int windowPosX = 100;    //Window mode's top-left corner x
int windowPosY = 100;


//Main function: GLUT runs as a console application starting at main()

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);                 //Enable double buffered mode
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth,windowHeight);     //Initial window width and height
    glutInitWindowPosition(windowPosX,windowPosY);    //Initial window top-left corner(x,y)
    glutCreateWindow("Bouncing Ball"); 
    glutMouseFunc(onMouse);
    glutMotionFunc(onMotion);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);                  //Register callback handler for window re-paint
    //glutMouseFunc(mouseClicks);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);    
    glutPostRedisplay();                           //Register callback handler for window re-shape
    glutTimerFunc(0,Timer,0);                          //First timer call immediately
    initGL();                                          //Our own OpenGL initialization
    glutMainLoop();                                    //Enter event processing loop

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Omitting the drawing code for the ball, you have this code sequence:

```
glLoadIdentity();    //Reset model-view matrix
glTranslatef(ballX,ballY,0.0f);  //Translate to (xPos,yPos)
...
glRasterPos2f(-1.0,0.0);
glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'S');
```

The current modelview transformation is applied to the position you specify with `glRasterPos2f()`, which includes the translation you specified with `glTranslatef()`.

You have a few options to fix this:

1. Reset the transformation before calling `glRasterPos2f()`:

   ```
   glLoadIdentity();
   glRasterPos2f(-1.0,0.0);
   glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'S');
   ```
2. Push/pop the transformation you use for drawing the ball, to restore the previous transformation after you finished drawing the ball:

   ```
   glLoadIdentity();    //Reset model-view matrix
   glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef(ballX,ballY,0.0f);  //Translate to (xPos,yPos)
   ...
   glPopMatrix();
   glRasterPos2f(-1.0,0.0);
   glutBitmapCharacter (GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,'S');
   ```
3. Use `glWindowPos()` instead of `glRasterPos()`, which allows you to specify the position in pixels, instead of coordinates that will be transformed.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Sir, I have fixed that issue

Comment: I have a new problem now, how to display the score. please have a look at the code

Comment: what header is glWindowPos() in? - warning: implicit declaration of function ‘glWindowPos2f’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: Also, for some reason glWindowPos2f() always prints to the bottom left and ignores the x,y parameters!